# Angular/Node/Express/Passport - Issues when connecting to facebook(CORS)

Tags: facebook, node.js, angularjs, express, cors

i'm trying to use facebook authentication on my NodeJs server. i came to the tutorial of http://scotch.io/ and have it working locally when using a REST client(Postman, etc).

To improve the UI i used Angular JS as a front end. but when i call a http.get to my specific route given on the NodeJs back-end i get the following error in chome and firefox:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…0%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=3000000000006. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

i've tried several solutions on StackOverflow but its still not working...
my NodeJs uses Express 4.* and a CORS middleware.
for Angular i found several ways to enable CORS, none working so far.

I hope you can help me:D Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to do an ajax request to the facebook.com-url that you have in your post. Facebook doesn't allow you to do that. And I don't understand what it would do you most likely want to open up that url in a popup or redirect to it

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having the same issues

Comment: @LarissaLeite, no i haven't yet

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'window.location="http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook"';` in your **Angular Controller** from where you send the request to your **Express Server** which contains `passport.authenticate` stuff.

This will stop your angular to call facebook auth dialogue page as AJAX request.

It works for me!

Comment: looks and feels like a hack. is that the only way!?

Comment: Yes, I didn't found the solution but anyhow managed it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular with Node/Express as well, and the following function works for me with my own backend services (I'm currently not using it with Facebook to be honest), so just check it out:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"); // 24 hours

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Then, you need to use it tin the `app.confiure()`method as follows:

```
// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
   app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    ...
});
```

It's important to use it BEFORE all other directrives!

Comment: Hmm, well i tried it! not working so far, the origin changes to localhost:8080 after my first call, thats where the issue come from

Comment: this doesn't apply to the case in the question above. the problem there is that the response from facebook doesn't have the CORS headers set. The reason Postman has no problem is because it doesn't check for the CORS headers as the browser does (for security reasons). You can solve the problem by making a simple location.href instead of the http.get

Comment: Will try that out! @Andreas Thanks for the response