# Send user details to controller in passport authenticate using google-oauth2

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

I have created a google user session using passport oauth, using the following routes:

```
nodeApp.get('/api/google', googlepassport.authenticate('google', { session: true,scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
nodeApp.get('/auth/google/callback',

        googlepassport.authenticate('google', 

        {              //  successRedirect: '/',

           // failureRedirect: '/login-error',


        }))
```

At the backend in `passport.serializeuser`, I am able to retrieve details however I want to send these details to client controller.

I tried using `Http.get`, but that doesn't work for google oauth as I get cross domain error. I am new to nodejs, so kindly suggest best possible way to do send user details to client controller.

google strategy

```
googlepassport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "add",
    clientSecret: "",
    callbackURL: "---",
    // passReqToCallback: true
    },

    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // make the code asynchronous
        // console.log("test google");
        // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Google
        process.nextTick(function() {
            console.log("test google");
            //console.log(profile);

            var userMap = {};
            userMap['mail'] = profile.emails[0].value;
            userMap['name'] = profile.displayName;
            //  console.log(JSON.stringify(userMap));
            //  req.user = req.session.googlepassport.user;
            //console.log(req.session);
            //req.session.user = req.session.googlepassport.user;
            return done(null, userMap);
        })
                //  done(null,null);
}));

googlepassport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('Serializing');
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user);
});

googlepassport.deserializeUser(function(userMap, done) {
     done(null, userMap);
});
```

I want to send `userMap` to the `client`, Here the route is made through `href`, to avoid `cross-domain` error, that I get if I use it on `button` click .

Comment: can you show your `serializeuser` code, and also, what all details you want to send to the client? Please show your user schema also.

Comment: @RaviShankar I have posted the code, Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: are you using `express()`?

Comment: no till now, can you give me pointers to use it

Comment: how are you handling your routes then?

Comment: 1.  use href to rediect to routes, 2. controller which calls http.get () to route -- but this gives cross error

Comment: i meant to ask, how are you handling the get and post routes in your server? Is there a way i caan have a look at your whole code, github or something?

Comment: Sorry that might not be feasible, I am not using express to handle routes,  I am directly calling the route from angular  and  the code of route is mentioned, I hope I could provide the details

Comment: To avoid this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029627/angular-node-express-passport-cross-domain-problems-enable-cors-passport-faceb  , I call the passport authenticate route using href, but then unable to retrieve user details at client

Comment: i need to look at the backend code.