# CORS redirection problem with Spotify API?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, spotify

My web application is using Angular 12 for the front end and Node.js 12.16.0 in the backend w/ Express.js. I am trying to develop a web application allowing the user to login with their Spotify API but I am having a lot of trouble with CORS even after looking up a bunch of posts. From the front end, my code is is just calling my `/login` endpoint using HttpClient.

```
public login(): Observable<any> {
    const url = backendURL + BackendEndpoints.Login;

    return this.http.get<any>(url, {withCredentials: true});
}
```

From the backend, my endpoint setup looks like this with the appropriate variables filled in which should redirect my front end webpage to the Spotify login page.

```
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    var state = generateRandomString(16);

    var scope = 'user-read-email playlist-read-private'
    res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
        querystring.stringify({
            response_type: 'code',
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: scope,
            redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
            state: state,
            show_dialog: true
        }));
});
```

I am also using the cors package as well in my middleware.

```
this.expressApp.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:4200', credentials: true}));
```

My front end does not redirect and instead gets this CORS error.

> Cross-origin redirection to https://accounts.spotify.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Fauthorize%3Fscope%3Duser-read-email%2Bplaylist-read-private%26response_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A4200%252Fjoin%26state%3DjOZBRfRFxNi3auk6%26client_id%3D7e37838f2aa3449da5ee2b592a1a185e%26show_dialog%3Dtrue denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Why am I getting CORS errors still? If possible, I'd like to just configure my backend instead of making a proxy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : Not working

Did you try to add the Origin in the headers of the angular call ?
Something like that :

```
public login(): Observable<any> {
    const url = backendURL + BackendEndpoints.Login;
    const header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.append('Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

    return this.http.get<any>(url, {withCredentials: true, headers: header});
}
```

Edit2 :

You can try to create the a link :

```
 <a href="/login" #spotifyConnectLink></a>
```

Then you create a button to ask the user to click to connect :

```
 <button (click)='handleCacheAndLaunchConnection()'>Connect To Spotify</button>
```

On your ts you create the handleCacheAndLaunchConnection function and you force the click on the a link with Viewchild :

```
 @ViewChild('spotifyConnectLink') spotifyConnectLink: ElementRef;

 handleCacheAndLaunchConnection() {
     //Do the stuff you need for app and cache

    let el: HTMLElement = this.spotifyConnectLink.nativeElement;
    el.click();
 }
```

Hope this work

Comment: Just tried it. Now I'm getting a different error: "[Spotify API Link] denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin http://localhost:4200 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: I found something that maybe will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029627/angular-node-express-passport-cross-domain-problems-enable-cors-passport-faceb  They say to use a <a> like that : `<a href="/auth/facebook"></a>`

Comment: for you're example you can try to do : <a href="/login"></a>

Comment: This works but I'd much rather call a function on the frontend because there are some things I want to generate in my application and cache.

Comment: Very smart! Thanks!