# CORS issue on NativeScript Facebook authentication with Node.js and Passport

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, nativescript, passport-facebook

I've implemented Facebook OAuth on Noje.js via Passport library. The URL that invokes Facebook OAuth `/auth/facebook` and the Facebook callback URL `/auth/facebook/callback` are as follows:

```
loginRouter.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

loginRouter.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {successRedirect: "/rs/login/me"}));
```

I have two front-end applications, one is on the web (Angular2) and the other is on mobile (Nativescript). Firstly, I tried implementing the front-end on Angular2 and made an Ajax call to `/auth/facebook`, which received no response. Further research have revealed that although I've set the Express.js properties to handle CORS properties like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    next();
});
```

the response from facebook doesn't have the CORS headers set [(stackoverflow link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753965/angular-node-express-passport-issues-when-connecting-to-facebookcors). Therefore the solution I've adapted was simply to use `<a href>` element which does not check the CORS header on response [(solution is here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029627/angular-node-express-passport-cross-domain-problems-enable-cors-passport-faceb), which made everything run perfectly on Angular2.

But when it comes to NativeScript, I cannot find any way to avoid this CORS problem. I'm using the fetch module to make an Http GET request to Node.js with the URL `/auth/facebook` like this:

```
public loginFB() {
    return fetchModule.fetch("http://[MY_SERVER_IP]/auth/facebook", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'GET' 
    }).then(handleErrors);
};
```

Although I've set the request mode to "no-cors", this solution simply doesn't work. I've tried to set the CORS headers again on preflight, either at `/auth/facebook` and `/auth/facebook/callback` methods, but still, nothings happening. My HTTP request enters the `/auth/facebook` method but as far as I observed, neither of the middleware and the callback of `/auth/facebook/callback` method is invoked. What might be the solution?

Comment: did you find a better solution to this problem?

Comment: It's been a real long time but you can find my answer below telling that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Yes I know but I quite don’t get it how you implemented the passport strategy with the solution below...

Comment: I'm sorry but I've found the github issue I've opened to nativescript-facebook-login repo that I mentioned below. Here is the link, hope it helps: https://github.com/AntonioCuevaUrraco/nativescript-facebook-login/issues/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use Facebook GraphAPI by being inspired via https://github.com/AntonioCuevaUrraco/nativescript-facebook-login. By using this approach, I've imported the Facebook GraphAPI for Android and used it that way.